# How to navigate between two pages while using MVVM?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, navigation

I am new to MVVM and can't find how to do the following:

I have MainPage.xaml and ElementOnePage.xaml

When somebody double tap an element of the main page, I want to display the ElementOnePage.
MainPage display a list, ElementOnePage display the detail

My MainPage DataContext is of type ElementViewModel

1) Should my ElementOnePage DataContext also be the same ?

2) I am using QueryString parameters to pass the information about which element has been selected.

However when I retrieve the element in the **OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)** function, this is too late.

I tried defining the DataContext of the page in this method, but it didn't work.

So how can I have a page that do the expected behavior while using effectively data binding ?

Comment: Why is OnNavigatedTo "too late"?

Comment: I don't know. I just happens that when I put the code here, there is no data binding done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used MVVMLight for my WP7 apps. MVVMLight uses behaviors for command binding.

1. Create a RelayCommand in your MainPageViewModel, call it say NavigateToElementOneCommand.
2. Create a EventToCommand behavior on the ListBox, and bind it to the NavigatToElementOneCommand. 
   (Assuming that MainPageViewModel is set as MainPage's DataContext).
3. In NavigateToElementCommand, write the code to navigate to the ElementOnePage.XAML.